# Does Stripe connect support recuring payment?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, recurring-billing

I recently started reading the Stripe connect doc, which I've been following, but it seems like it supports only one time. I'm creating a project where sellers can create a membership plan and user's can subscribe to them. How can I achieve this, please? (I'm using nodejs by the way.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - typically you will want to attempt to write some code after researching it online or doing tutorials.  Once you have done this post you code / errors here for support.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Stripe Billing supports Connect. There are a few different ways to set this up, so it really depends on your business model.

Here's a good starting place: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/subscriptions